# Is there a way to get a variable from another script?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I created a chrome extension, the extension needs to get a variable from a script to use it in another context, i can access the variable using browser console but i can't access it by my extension using `window.VARIABLE_NAME`

```
const getCodeBtn= document.getElementById('get-code-btn');

async function getCode() {
  let [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true });
  chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: { tabId: tab.id },
    function: addCode,
  })
}

//we need to add code in a website input
function addCode() {
  const input = document.getElementById('some-id');
  const btn = document.getElementById('some-id');

  input.value = window.code;  //window.code is undefined
  console.log(window.code)  // undefined
  btn.click();
}

getCodeBtn.addEventListener('click', getCode)
```

I still can access the variable value in browser console

```
code;  // 1235469
```

Comment: where are you setting `window.code`

Comment: @Bravo  the varaible in a certain script run in the website itself, my code is just an extension that work on that website to get the code from the script to place it in a website input

Comment: From Chrome 95+, use `chrome.scripting.executeScript({world: 'MAIN', target: {tabId: tab.id}, func: addCode})`

Comment: @IvánNokonoko it works thank you, you can add your answer so i can accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/scripting/#type-ScriptInjection), from Chrome 95+ you can choose the execution environment to run the script in with the `world` parameter. So, in order to run in the web page's environment, your injection should be something like:

```
chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: { tabId: tab.id },
    func: addCode,
    world: 'MAIN'
  })
```